# How do I add column headers for each row of data in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python3.6.

Database table example:

```
column1 . .column2  . .column3

....10    ...........20..............30

....100  .......     200.............300
```

Code:

```
# extracts all data for the rows without the column names
rows=cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

  10   20   30  
  100  200  300
```

How do I add the column names manually to this loop so that it is included in the output?

I am new to stackoverflow so this post will need improvements in formatting, content, etc., so I welcome any feedback.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cursor.description`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes) to extract headers and then iterate headers and data via [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

headers = [list(map(itemgetter(0), cursor.description))]
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in chain(headers, rows):
    print(*row)

column1 column2 column3
10 20 30
100 200 300
```

If formatting as a table with consistent spacing is important, see [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data).

Comment: `headers = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]` from PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0 [Cursor Attributes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Thanks, updated. I wasn't familiar with `cursor`. Just have to put it in another list for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

if you're adding column names manually just do print the column names outside of the for loop.

```
print("col1\tcol2\tcol3")
for row in rows:
   print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the headers to be available with each row of data, make a `DictCursor`. In my knowledge, most popular MySQL, Oracle, Postgres libs support it.

Then you can do this:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host,port,user,passwd,db)
cursor = van.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table;")

# Avoid doing fetchall(). If your query resukt is big enough, it can even make your program run out of available memory of the system.
#rows=cursor.fetchall()

#Alternatively, iterate over the cursor itself, which is a generator

for row in cursor:
    print row
```

Reference: [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)